# Does Crystal have attribute accessor methods like in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, attributes, accessor, crystal-lang

Does the [Crystal programming language](https://crystal-lang.org/) have an equivalent to Ruby's attribute accessor methods? More specifically, does Crystal have equivalents to the following?

- `attr_accessor`
- `attr_reader`
- `attr_writer`

?

Comment: You mean Object#getter, Object#setter, and Object#property.  Sure its in the [Docs](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.8/syntax_and_semantics/methods_and_instance_variables.html#getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they're defined as macro.

Basically:

| ruby | crystal |
| --- | --- |
| attr_accessor | property |
| attr_reader | getter |
| attr_writer | setter |

Example

```
class Person
  property name
end
```

is equal to

```
class Person
  def name=(@name)
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end
```

For more details see the [Reference](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.8.2/Object.html)

Comment: It is my sincere wish that you are currently utilizing Crystal. I have a straightforward inquiry: Is it now possible to run Crystal on a Windows operating system? The last time I checked, this was not supported.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I am using Crystal, and it's possible to use it on Windows, but unfortunately I might not be a good judge on how enjoyable it really is (dll support etc) because I myself don't often use Windows. It can always be used to almost full potential if you use WSL, which might or not qualify as proper "Windows". Long story short, it doesn't have first class support yet but its getting there and ppl are pushing hard to get this done. Quote: "All the main platform features for Windows are finished!" Read about it here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5430

Comment: Thanks @Andre_Wildberg. I should have known Crystal would make it that easy.